# Adding attributes to the path request with twig in symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig, routes

I've been googleing this question but I can't find anyone with my same problem... And I don't think I'm the only one here >.<

Let's see, I'm using translations in symfony2. I NEED to use twig for this...
The thing is that I need 3 links so people can change the site's language. The link has to redirect to the same page the user is, but changing the '_locale'.

I first thought in something like this:

```
// in routing.yml
bundleStuff_someUrl:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/aloha
    defaults: { _controller: bundleStuff:Aloha:foo }

bundleStuff_fooUrl:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/foo/{fooParam}
    defaults: { _controller: bundleStuff:Foo:foo }

// in view.html.twig
<a href="{{ path((app.request.get('_route'), { '_locale': 'l1' }) }}">lang1</a>
<a href="{{ path((app.request.get('_route'), { '_locale': 'l2' }) }}">lang2</a>
<a href="{{ path((app.request.get('_route'), { '_locale': 'l3' }) }}">lang3</a>
```

The problem becomes when (in this case) the _route is fooUrl... Is there a way to append every attribute I have in the current view to the path I'm looking for? 
In other words referring to this example: is there a way so twig knows it has to add the 'fooParam' to the path if the current view is 'fooUrl'?

Thank's in advance!
Hope this post is useful! :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`_route_params` request attribute holds the parameters of the current route. So the twig code would be,

```
{% set route = app.request.get('_route') %}
{% set route_params = app.request.get('_route_params') %}

<a href="{{ path(route, route_params | merge({ '_locale': 'l1' })) }}">lang1</a>
<a href="{{ path(route, route_params | merge({ '_locale': 'l2' })) }}">lang2</a>
<a href="{{ path(route, route_params | merge({ '_locale': 'l3' })) }}">lang3</a>
```

Comment: Notice that this _route_params attribute is only available in Symfony 2.1. If you use 2.0 you can use a custom twig extension as described here: http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html

Comment: Sorry, wrong url. The right one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378714/get-current-url-in-twig-template

Comment: Uo! Thank's to both of you! :D
I'll try this at home and tell you what. Thx so much!

Comment: Ok, I had to do the twig extension since I'm using 2.0 (or 2.1 beta, not sure xD ).
I got it running :D

Answer (score 1):

For symfony 2.0 yo can get _locale variable in the controller and after send in a variable.

For example

Controller:

```
    $language = $this->getRequest()->get('_locale'); 
    $this->$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('bundleStuff_someUrl', array('language' => $language)))
```

and after in routing.yml

bundleStuff_someUrl:
    pattern:  /{language}/aloha
    defaults: { _controller: bundleStuff:Aloha:foo }