# Get id from the referer URL?

Tags: symfony, twig

get the current path in a Twig  (and not the full URL), i.e. I don't want http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/content/tag/1, I only need /1

Comment: possible duplicate of [get current url in twig template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378714/get-current-url-in-twig-template)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a variable on your route called tag right?

You can get it like this:

```
{{ app.request.get('tag') }}
```