# If statement in Twig (for Particle in Joomla)

Tags: twig, joomla3.0

Trying to edit a particle in Joomla -- I'm fairly new to twig and I'm trying to list information based on a selection in vertical tabs. I have an on-click refresh for my li edit that makes a tab "selected" and creates my internal url:

```
  {% for item in particle.items %}
    <li>
        <a href="/Joomla/about-the-library/locations#{{ loop.index }}">{{ item.title|e }}
        <img src="{{ url(item.image)|e }}" alt="{{ item.title|e }}">
        <div class="g-flexslider-carousel-item-image-preview-icon"></div>
        </a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

This is all well and good, but I ran into an issue when trying to display the data associated with the selected item. I tried to create a variable to check my items against, but the variable doesn't seem to be coming back as an integer, and I've tried a few things:

```
 {% set branch = app.request.pathinfo|trim('/Joomla/about-the-library/locations#') %}
          {% if loop.index == branch %}
                <div class="g-flexslider-showcase-item-content-container">
                    <div class="g-flexslider-showcase-item-image">
                        <img src="{{ url(item.image)|e }}" alt="{{ item.title|e }}">
                    </div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

(I found that [get current url in twig template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378714/get-current-url-in-twig-template/9384118#) helped, but I'm not sure I'm using the answers provided correctly. I've also sifted through the [Twig Documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation) for a couple hours to no avail.)

[Nov 2016] - This is still what "my" code looks like for this section. It seems to *just* be a problem with this if statement, as the "else" statement (which I'm using for debugging purposes) keeps coming through.

`{% for item in particle.items %} 
                {% if  app.request.get('name') == item.URLname|e %}
                    <p>You have branched {{ item.title|e }} correctly. </p>`

Comment: The problem is that `url fragments` are never sent towards the server. Would it hurt to use the `querystring` or `rewriting` the url?

Comment: Thanks @DarkBee, that explains that. I've converted to a query string solution, but my if statement (  `{% if item.URLname == app.request.query.all %}` ) still seems to be failing. I may be using the wrong command to pull my query string. Still working on that.

Comment: It looks like my strings are returning empty. I've tried: 
`item.app.query.all `, `item.app.query.get('name')`, and even `item.request.pathinfo`. (I've also tried several permutations that I didn't feel should return anything. They didn't.) I think I'm having a more intricate issue than I had supposed.

Comment: Update your question with the new aproach?

Comment: fyi its `app.request.get('name')`, not `item.app.....`

Comment: Thanks @DarkBee. 

Coming full circle 6 months later, I'm back to this problem. It's now one small floating change I'd like to make on this template. I still haven't had to use twig for anything else, but I've been trying to read up on this. I keep wondering if maybe I'm having an issue with the container -- I wish I could debug web dev easier than trial and error. My for loop and if are listed above as they stand now.