# get route controllers/action within rendered subcomponent in symfony3

Tags: symfony

In my base.html.twig I render a component:

```
{% block header %}
    {{ render(controller("AppBundle:Application\\Header:header")) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Is there a way to get the current route action/controller? i.e. the current url in the browser?

When I do var_dump($request->get('_route'));die; it results in null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get current url in twig template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378714/get-current-url-in-twig-template)

Comment: Dont think so as when i try that, i get this: 
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "" as such route does not exist.").

Comment: Actually would be this:$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]. Is there a helper service to get this data? A wrapper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want get the actual route, in your controller you can get the master request like this:

```
$this->container->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest()->get('_route');
```

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't answer through a comment, I have to write this as an answer.

As mentionned above, this question might be a duplicate of:
[Get current URL in Twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378714/get-current-url-in-twig-template)

To get both the name of the current route and the current URL you can simply render them within your twig template by:

```
<p><strong>current route name</strong> :{{app.request.attributes.get('_route')}}</p>
<p><strong>current url: </strong> {{ app.request.schemeAndHttpHost ~ app.request.requestUri }}</p>
```

Comment: I did try that and it prints this: current route name :

current url: http : //localhost:8000/_fragment?_path=_format%3Dhtml%26_locale%3Den%26_controller%3DAppBundle%253AApplication%255CHeader%253Aheader