# Dynamic path symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this code:

```
href="{{ path('new') }}"
```

Now is necessary use one variable in this section:

```
href="{{ path(item.ruta) }}"
```

But this show a error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "" as such route does
>   not exist.").

How can solution this problem?

Comment: It seems that `item.ruta` is empty, so no route could be generated. You could specifiy a fallback like this `{{ path(item.ruta ? item.ruta : 'new') }}`

Comment: Thanks Fabian. Now show this error with this code: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "#" as such route does not exist.")."

Comment: It is not a solution, the item.ruta is inside a loop. The idea is to assign the content of item.ruta within path

Comment: What do you mean with `The idea is to assign the content of item.route within path` ?

Comment: Sorry Fabian, is perfect your solution, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `item.ruta` is empty, so no route could be generated.

You could specifiy a fallback like this `{{ path(item.ruta ? item.ruta : 'new') }}` or if you want to stay on the current page you need to do something like descripted here: [get current url in twig template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378714/get-current-url-in-twig-template)

```
{% if item.ruta %}
    href="{{ path(item.ruta) }}"
{% else %}
    href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) }}"
{% endif %}
```

or if you really want `#` only, then remove the `path` function call

```
{% if item.ruta %}
    href="{{ path(item.ruta) }}"
{% else %}
    href="#"
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `<a href="{{ item.ruta ? item.ruta : '#' }}">...</a>`