# Twig : how to check if there's a request ? (looking for symfony 5 : app.request)

Tags: php, symfony, if-statement, request, twig

I'm trying to check through Twig if there is a request in order to show the results of my searchBar, in Twig, **ONLY** if there is a request.

I found old symfony docs on app.request, but it doesn't seem to work for my 5.2 Symfony Project (here is my twig template) :

```
{% if app.request %}
    <h3 class="main-header_h3">Résultats de la recherche</h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="grid">
        {% for product in products %}
            {% include 'product/_card.html.twig' with {product: product} only %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <hr>
{%endif %}
```

Problem here is that my `{% if app.request %}` isn't being interpreted, so I get my whole `product` database coming on my view.
If you need any more code, let me know (Controller/Repository...) but the request definitely works, it's just my rendering in Twig that gives me trouble using that `if`.

Comment: Isn't there always a request? Are you trying to check the request method (GET, POST, etc.)?

Comment: There is indeed always an `app.request` that would at least contain the URI accessed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20329384/2123530 To get yourself out of this: [`dump`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html) it.  `({ dump(app.request) }}` will help you compare what is in that variable/object and what you did expect there.

Comment: Do you want to do something like this: `{% if app.request.query.get('search', null)  %}` where `search` is the url param?

Comment: @bechir, yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. My URL parameter is 'search', and I want to to check using Twig if it's there or not, and if it is, then `include` a partial i've made.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bechir, the solution to checking if my URL has a 'search' parameter in it using TWIG is :

> `{% if app.request.query.get('search', null)  %}` where search is the
> url parameter. (from : bechir)

So this is what it now looks like, and I do have my partial `product/_card.html.twig` loaded only when there's a URL parameter `search`:

```
{% if app.request.query.get('search', null) %}
    <h3 class="main-header_h3">Résultats de la recherche :</h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="grid">
        {% for product in products %}
            {% include 'product/_card.html.twig' with {product: product} only %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <hr>
{% endif %}
```